# Setting a heap memory above 4096MB on Karaf

Tags: java, jvm, apache-karaf, karaf

I'm using a java application which requires a lot of memory, and I'd like to be able to set the maximum available memory for the JVM to a value above 4096MB, such as 8192MB.

I tried using the following parameter:

```
wrapper.java.maxmemory
```

which seems to work fine under the 4096MB threshold, but not above (it is stuck at something like 3.7GB or so).

I'm using a 64b JVM.

Where is the piece of code that prevents me from going above 4096MB?

Comment: Are you sure you're using a 64bit JVM?

Comment: yes, java -version returns OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM

Answer (score 5, accepted):

unfortunaly, the limit of `wrapper.java.maxmemory` is hardcoded in the version used in Karaf (wrapper.c, v3.2.3) :

```
/* Maximum JVM memory */
maxMemory = getIntProperty(properties, "wrapper.java.maxmemory", 0);
if (maxMemory > 0) {
    maxMemory = __min(__max(maxMemory, initMemory), 4096);  /* initMemory <= n <= 4096 */
    if (strings) {
        strings[index] = malloc(sizeof(char) * (5 + 4 + 1));  /* Allow up to 4 digits. */
        sprintf(strings[index], "-Xmx%dm", maxMemory);
    }
    index++;
}
```

You should use something like `wrapper.java.additional.1 = -Xmx8196m`

Comment: I cannot find this file in sources of karaf (wrapper.c), where is file located, what project? I am looking on mirror on github (official), thx.

Comment: The "wrapper" is not related to karaf. You can find the project here : https://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/english/download.jsp I don't think the sources are on github.

Comment: Ahh, I see thanks, otherwise using additional.n works

Comment: To have `wrapper.java.additional.1=-Xmx8196m` to be taken into account, you have either to set `wrapper.java.maxmemory=0` or comment the line `#wrapper.java.maxmemory=4096`. You can check with `wrapper.java.additional.2=-XX:+PrintFlagsFinal` and look at `data/log/wrapper.log`